# Which is the role of invoking the default package in beamer?

Tags: beamer, kile

In Kile, when one creates a new beamer presentation using the standard templates the file includes a call to the "default" package in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{default}
```

I am puzzled that commenting out it does not seem to make any change. I googled around and could not find any info, either in the beamer user guide or in this site. Does anyone know what the purpose of this is?

Comment: Is that not `\usetheme{default}`? That would be the default theme for beamer, which is loaded _by default_ anyway.

Comment: @marczellm no, it is really "\usepackage{default}"

Comment: http://ctan.org/pkg/default

Comment: Thanks @marczellm, but that does not seem very informative..

Comment: IMHO, this is a bug in Kile. They meant to insert `\usetheme{default}`.

Comment: I am also beginning to believe that @karlkoeller. Will check in their bug site

Comment: as @karlkoeller said this is a bug. The fix for this would be trivial, just edit [this file](https://projects.kde.org/projects/extragear/office/kile/repository/revisions/master/entry/src/data/templates/template_Beamer.tex), open a bug on the [KDE bugtracker](http://bugs.kde.org) and attach the edited file so that the dev can push it into master for the new version of Kile, to be released soon (but unfortunately not in this timeline ;)).

Comment: @dcmst Can you add an answer, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already noted in the comments, this is a harmless bug in the `beamer` template offered by Kile. Instead of

```
\usetheme{default}
```

the author of the template wrote

```
\usepackage{default}
```

To "fix" the problem locally it is possible to create a new file located in `~/.kde/share/apps/kile/templates/template-Beamer.tex` file[1][2] with the following content:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

$$INPUTENCODING$$

\usetheme{default}   %this line could be also completely removed    
\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

The new file will overwrite the default template.

An even better solution would be to open a bug report in the [Kile/KDE bugtracker](https://bugs.kde.org/) and attach to it a fixed version of the template file, so that the devs will be happy and the fix will be included in the next release.

[1]: in some systems KDE apps files are stored in `.kde4` and not `.kde`

[2]: this only works for Linux users